# How to sum total row each month group by month and user name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sales record table for every month. Every salesman have their own code `bd` and `nk` in this case.

**MySQL**

```
select sale_plc
      , month(sale_date) as mon
      , sum(sale_cost) as cost 
from daily_sales 
 where year(sale_date)='2016' 
group 
    by year(sale_date)
      , month(sale_date)
      , sale_plc 
order 
    by month(sale_date)
      , sale_plc asc 
 LIMIT 0, 30
```

After the query I've got this result:

```
id  mon cost
bd  1   224787
nk  1   721102
bd  2   440399
nk  2   898020
bd  3   363543
nk  3   878250
```

While

- **id**=salesman code(sale_plc)
- **mon**=month number
- **cost**=total sale of this month from this ID.

According to the result. I expect the result with array like this.
Array

```
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [mon] => 1
            [bd] => 224787
            [nk] => 721102
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [mon] => 2
            [bd] => 440399
            [nk] => 898020
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [mon] => 3
            [bd] => 363543
            [nk] => 878250
        )
    )
```

I know that it is something to do with the `sale_plc`. I need to make it array but I don't have an idea to do so.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? They are not the same thing, and may change the syntax of you query.

Comment: I've removed the sql-server tag based on the syntax of the sql query - specifically the `Limit` keyword that belongs to MySql and can't be used with Sql-Server.

Comment: This is a simple 1-dimensional to 2-dimensional array transformation in PHP

Comment: @sean mysql, so what's is the best solution when the syntax is correct?

Comment: @Strawberry please show me how simple is it.

Comment: Note that year(sale_date) is redundant within the group by clause

Comment: @Strawberry I plan to use `year(sale_date)` again next year.

Comment: That makes no difference.

Comment: @Strawberry, so would you please suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: Can I achieve this with only mysql or do I need a help of PHP too?

Comment: @Wilf, Where you got these results?? You tag this post as PHP, so if you use it in PHP, that gives you the array as output.

Comment: @FrayneKonok, I didn't have these results yet. I just write it to demonstrate what I want. I tag as PHP because it might have something to do with it. I expect the answer not investigation.

Comment: @Wilf, OKey Let me do it for you.

Comment: @Wilf, Try my answer.

Comment: @Wilf, I update my code with my own creation array like your SQL output and the result is same you want.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have you SQL output, so i create an array and make my own code with the same functionality as i do for your array.

**PHP**

```
$arr = array(array("id" => "bd", "mon" => "1", "cost" => "224787"),
            array("id" => "nk", "mon" => "1", "cost" => "721102"),
            array("id" => "bd", "mon" => "2", "cost" => "440399"),
            array("id" => "nk", "mon" => "2", "cost" => "898020"),
            array("id" => "bd", "mon" => "3", "cost" => "363543"),
            array("id" => "nk", "mon" => "3", "cost" => "878250"),
            );

$output_arr = array();      
$tmp = 0;
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($tmp == 0 || $tmp != $value['mon'])
        $output_arr[$value['mon']][mon] = $value['mon'];
    if($value['id'] == 'bd')
        $output_arr[$value['mon']][$value['id']] = $value['cost'];
    if($value['id'] == 'nk')
        $output_arr[$value['mon']][$value['id']] = $value['cost'];
    $tmp = $value['mon'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output_arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [mon] => 1
            [bd] => 224787
            [nk] => 721102
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mon] => 2
            [bd] => 440399
            [nk] => 898020
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [mon] => 3
            [bd] => 363543
            [nk] => 878250
        )

)
```

> I have already answer With your SQL Output. Given the example with your SQL.

**PHP**

```
$output_arr = array();
//Your sql
$sql = "select sale_plc
      , month(sale_date) as mon
      , sum(sale_cost) as cost 
from daily_sales 
 where year(sale_date)='2016' 
group 
    by year(sale_date)
      , month(sale_date)
      , sale_plc 
order 
    by month(sale_date)
      , sale_plc asc 
 LIMIT 0, 30";
$tmp = 0;
$i = 0;
$qry = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($qry )){
    if($tmp == 0 || $tmp != $obj->mon)
        $output_arr[$obj->mon][mon] = $obj->mon;
    if($obj->id == 'bd')
        $output_arr[$obj->mon][$obj->id] = $obj->cost;
    if($obj->id == 'nk')
        $output_arr[$obj->mon][$obj->id] = $obj->cost;
    $tmp = $obj->mon;
}

print_r($output_arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array(
[1] => Array
    (
        [mon] => 1
        [bd] => 224787
        [nk] => 721102
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [mon] => 2
        [bd] => 440399
        [nk] => 898020
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [mon] => 3
        [bd] => 363543
        [nk] => 878250
    )
)
```

Try this answer, if any problem then please let me know.

Comment: Frayne, thanks for your help but the result comes like this:

`Array ( [1] => Array ( [mon] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [mon] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [mon] => 3 ) )`